# document.getElementsById("...").innerHTML doesnt change h2 tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

After `document.getElementsById("occ").innerHTML = "Already registered";` tag `<h2 style="color: red" id ="occ"></h2>` doesn't change, but page looks like it reloaded.
Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ustory - Register</title>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="CSS_defaults.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="Ustory_JS.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<?php
    if($_GET['occupied'] == "true") {
        echo($_GET['occupied']);
        $occupied = "true";
    }
?>

<script>
    var occ = <?php echo json_encode($occupied); ?>;
    alert(typeof(occ));
    if(occ == "true") {
        alert("done");
        document.getElementsById("occ").innerHTML = "Already registered";
    }
</script>

<div id="reg_in" class="reg" style="color:#FF4D50;">
  <form class="reg" name="register" action="U_story_reg.php" method="post" onsubmit="return register_()">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="Meno" required> <b>*</b><br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Priezvisko" required> <b>*</b><br>
    <input type="text" name="nick" id="nick" placeholder="Prezívka">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
    <input type="email" name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="E-mail" required> <b>*</b><br>
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Heslo" required> <b>*</b><br>
    <input type="password" name="pass_again" id="pass_again" placeholder="Heslo znovu" required> <b>*</b><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <h2 style="color: red" id ="occ"></h2>
  </form>
</div>
<h2 style="color: red" id ="occ"></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Do you have any idea why `document.getElementsById("occ").innerHTML = "Already registered";` doesn't work ?

Comment: Your browser console will have explanatory errors for you to look at.

Comment: *typo alert* it's `document.getElementById`

Comment: Also note that IDs should be unique for the whole displayed page otherwise use classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is executing before the DOM element has loaded & you have a typo in getElementsById should be getElementById. You have to either move the code below the html element you are trying to change or wrap it in a `$(document).ready` function. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var occ = <?php echo json_encode($occupied); ?>;
    alert(typeof(occ));
    if(occ == "true") {
        alert("done");
        document.getElementById("occ").innerHTML = "Already registered";
    }
 });
```

Comment: I think the problem is the typo in syntax, OP wrote `getElementsById`

Comment: The problem is both then. I'll update my answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried put <script>...</script> after <div>...</div> but I overlooked typo.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, make sure you reference the jQuery library in order to use the document.ready() method. Check out the link below for further information..
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_ready.asp